# PHP Regex into Array

Tags: php, regex

I have a few hundred lines coming from a VTT subtitle file, an example from the suttitle is

```
00:01:03.500 --> 00:01:03.510 align:start position:0%
<c.colorCCCCCC>fourth guess it came from a broken</c><c.colorE5E5E5> home
 </c>

00:01:03.510 --> 00:01:08.140 align:start position:0%
<c.colorCCCCCC>fourth guess it came from a broken</c><c.colorE5E5E5> home
a<00:01:04.580><c> father</c><00:01:05.580><c> not</c><00:01:05.820><c> being</c><00:01:05.880><c> there</c><00:01:06.890><c> my</c><00:01:07.890><c> mother</c></c>

00:01:08.140 --> 00:01:08.150 align:start position:0%
a<c.colorE5E5E5> father not being there my mother
 </c>

00:01:08.150 --> 00:01:13.429 align:start position:0%
a<c.colorE5E5E5> father not being there my mother</c>
<c.colorE5E5E5>getting<00:01:09.150><c> married</c><00:01:09.630><c> and</c><00:01:11.360><c> the</c><00:01:12.360><c> abuse</c></c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:01:12.659><c> started</c><00:01:13.049><c> at</c></c>

00:01:13.429 --> 00:01:13.439 align:start position:0%
<c.colorE5E5E5>getting married and the abuse</c><c.colorCCCCCC> started at
 </c>
```

I have this so far, but its dropping a few words as well as not capturing timecodes that are before -->

```
$matchthis= '~<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>|<c>\s*(?<text>.*?)</c>~';
if(preg_match_all($matchthis, $line, $allintag) or $blockstart){
```

I need the time captured and words in two arrays contained within one

```
array(
00:01:03.510,
00:01:04.580,
00:01:05.58,
00:01:05.820,
00:01:05.880,
00:01:06.890,
00:01:07.890,
00:01:08.140,
00:01:09.150,
00:01:09.630,
00:01:11.360,
00:01:12.360,
00:01:12.659,
00:01:13.049
)
array(
'fourth guess it came from a broken home',
'father',
'not',
'being',
'there',
'my',
'mother',
'getting',
'married',
'and',
'the',
'abuse',
'started',
'at'
)
```

Comment: Are the pair next or close to each other ?

Comment: `<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>.*?<c>\s*(?<text>.*?)\s*</c>`

Comment: `as well as not capturing timecodes that are before -->` If you have looked at your regex, you'd notice `<` and `>` surround the timecode expression. 
So, it's not going to match without those angle brackets.

Comment: Im using your expression, but its dropping words like "a"  on the new line. and not capturing the timecodes not in the tag  "00:01:03.500 -->"

Comment: So, Im not sure how to capture these

Comment: @PeterFriedlander edit your question slightly and let us know what is your expected output from the given string

Comment: `its dropping words like "a" on the new line`  ... `(?s)<(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)>.*?<c>\s*(?<text>.*?)\s*</c>`

Comment: And, are you saying you want to match something from `00:01:03.500 --> 00:01:03.510 align:start position:0%` as well ?

Comment: No, thank you for your reply. If you look at the code, for the first few words there isn't a starting tag with a timecode. The only thing that specifies the time is before -->. I need that time captured along with the words following